# Html2canvas:How to send mail with ataching screenshot (pdf) with javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I want to send my pdf ataching for mail, but need from help.
In my html page have  link which voice cry  function goPDF.

This is  my  function for generation on sreenshot(pdf).

```
    $scope.goPDF = function (id, type) {
    ID->id on my info for pdf.
    TYPE->This is text on pdf = automoto.pdf
                       $scope.link = "#/invoice/" + id;
            //Here get url to info for my pdf.        
            var invoicePDF = document.getElementById ('iFrame').contentWindow.document.getElementById ('sendPDF');
            //Here get all content for my pdf.     
        //Here make convert from html to canvas and finish canvas to pdf.    
                            $ ("#sendPDF").css ('background', '#fff');
                            html2canvas ($ (invoicePDF), {
                                onrendered: function (canvas) {
                                var pdf = new jsPDF ();
                                var marginLeft = 0;
                                var marginRight = 0;
                                pdf.addImage (canvas.toDataURL ("image/jpeg"), "jpeg", marginLeft, marginRight);
                                //pdf.save (type + '.pdf');
            //Here save pdf in my PC
                                var outputt = pdf.output ();
            //I do not where url on my pdf for ataching to mail.                       
                                }
                            });
```

Comment: you should specify the question, it's very vague now

Comment: I do not save pdf on my PC, i want this pdf ataching to mail i  send.I have html form for send bootstrap modal, but do not ataching pdf.